# boost tcp accept / connect takes too long

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, tcp

I have a server running very heavy 3D simulations that I want to display in real time on a client machine. For now I am running my tests in localhost to get rid of the network brandwidth and latency issues, and I use boost::asio to stream my data (geometry) through the network.
I have to use tcp because I have to compress my geometry, split it into multiple packages and then send it through the network, and on the client, gather the packages to rebuild my archive, so network packages have to arrive in the good order.

This works pretty well, I can run my simulation and stream my data at ~90-120fps, depending on the quantity of data to stream, which is very good.

My problem is that sometimes, it suddenly takes ~1second for the socket to connect() on the client, and consequently as much time for the server's to accept(). This causes my simulation to stop being streamed randomly, and I can't find the problem.

I though the problem could come from some kind of buffer overflow on the socket, preventing the server to write more data as long as the client didn't read some, but it can't be that, since I have no latency between the client and the server, so the client reads the packages fast enough (as soon as they arrive, basically)

Here's a shortened piece of code for the server:

```
while (1)
{
//archive some data in a stringstream using boost::archive...

    boost::asio::io_service ioservice;
    tcp::acceptor acceptor(ioservice, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), PORT));

    boost::system::error_code ignored_error;

    tcp::socket socket(ioservice);
    acceptor.accept(socket);

    gettimeofday(&m_tv, NULL);
    accept += (m_tv.tv_usec - m_timer);
    m_timer = m_tv.tv_usec;
    size_t bytes_sent = boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(ss.str()), boost::asio::transfer_all(), ignored_error);
}
```

and on the client I get something like:

```
while (1)
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    tcp::resolver::query query(IP, PORT);
    tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
    tcp::resolver::iterator end;
    tcp::socket socket(io_service);
    boost::system::error_code error = boost::asio::error::host_not_found;

    while (error && endpoint_iterator != end)
    {
       socket.close();
       socket.connect(*endpoint_iterator++, error);
    }
    if (error)
       throw boost::system::system_error(error);

    while(1)
    {
        boost::array<char, 200000> buf;
        ss.write(buf.data(), bytes_received);
        boost::system::error_code error;
        bytes_received = socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf), error);

        if (error == boost::asio::error::eof)
            break;
        else if (error)
            throw boost::system::system_error(error);
    }

}
```

I create a socket every frame, which is probably the problem, but I couldn't find an easier way of telling my client that he finished reading the package. By closing the socket every frame, I send eof to the client who then knows that he can build the archive using the data retrieved.

Is there something I can do to avoid opening a socket every frame, without having to check the content of my packages to know the size of the data to retrieve?

Comment: Just send the total size first.  Read the size value, then read that many bytes.  Then you're ready for the next size.

Comment: If you must repeat your socket connections, at least don't resolve the IP each time.  Just store the endpoint that works